# Proof that a recursively defined sequence is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This image contains both the question as well as the solution.
[image]

My issue with this is that they show using mathematical induction that $\sqrt{2}$ is a lower bound as $a_{n+1}\ge \sqrt{2}\forall \:n\in \mathbb{N}$ then in the very next statement it is said that $\sqrt{2}$ need not be a lower bound. Generally in such proofs it is said that $a_n\ge \sqrt{2}$ and then shown $a_{n+1}\ge \sqrt{2}$ too therefore $a_n\ge \sqrt{2}$. I had seen similar approach in real analysis textbooks, I am not sure how this is different and why it is said it is not a lower bound when the solution must be trying to prove that a lower bound exists, sequence is decreasing and therefore convergent.

I see the same issue over here too.
[image]

Comment: [[1]] In very intuitive way , what the Author is claiming is : lower bound is $min(\sqrt{2},a_1)$ [[2]] Starting with very large $a_1$ , lower bound is $\sqrt{2}$ [[3]] Starting with very small $a_1$ , lower bound is $a_1$ [[4]] Starting value is critical

Answer (score 1):

In order for $\sqrt 2$ to be a lower bound, you need $a_n\geq\sqrt 2$ for every $n\geq 1$. What they show is that $a_n\geq\sqrt 2$ for every $n\geq 2$ (not $1$). It might thus happen that $a_1<\sqrt 2$, in which case $\sqrt 2$ is not a lower bound of $(a_n)$. However, $a_1$ would be one in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Asserting that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N):a_{n+1}\geqslant\sqrt2$ is the same thing as asserting that $(\forall n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}):a_n\geqslant\sqrt2$. This is *not* the same thing as asserting that $\sqrt2$ is a lower bound of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$; it only asserts that it is a lower bound of the subsequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1\}}$. And it is clear that if $a_1<\sqrt2$, then it is false that $\sqrt2$ is a lower bound of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

Comment: I see but would one still be able to use monotone convergence theorem as done in the solution? I was under the assumption one had to prove that the entire sequence had a lower bound.

Comment: Yes, we can still use it. Suppose that $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ as a real sequence and that $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1,2,\ldots,k\}}$ is a monotone subsequence. Then $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N\setminus\{1,2,\ldots,k\}}$ converges, and therefore so does $(a_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$.

Comment: Ohk, so they are basically saying there exists a converging tail sequence therefore the sequence itself is convergent too. Thank you.